# How to show the “description” of a Hyperlink column in the Datasheet View ? (SharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list that uses a Hyperlink column (which contains the URL and description). When I use Datasheet View, I do not have the option to input the description field. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Right-click on the cell containing the link. Click the **Hyperlink** command and then click **Edit Hyperlink**.